# Spring Batch Partition Slave JDBCItemWriter StepScope or Default Bean Scope

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Please advise about the Spring batch partition Slave "`JdbcBatchItemWriter`" scope . Currently we have defined as default Bean scope with 30 partitions. As per the documentation says `JdbcBatchItemWriter` is thread-safe. Please note Our Reader is "STEPSCOPE"

Code snippets below for writer

```java
        @Bean
        public JdbcBatchItemWriter<UnifiedInvoiceDTO> summaryWriter() {
            JdbcBatchItemWriter<UnifiedInvoiceDTO> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
            databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
            databaseItemWriter.setSql(BSCSUtils.QUERY_INSERT_UBI_SUMMARY);
            ItemPreparedStatementSetter<UnifiedInvoiceDTO> invoicePreparedStatementSetter = new InvoiceSummarySetter();
            databaseItemWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(invoicePreparedStatementSetter);
            return databaseItemWriter;
        }
```

Code snippets below for Composite writer as we have multiple tables

```java
        @Bean
        public CompositeItemWriter compositeWriter() throws Exception {
            CompositeItemWriter compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter();
            List<ItemWriter> writers = new ArrayList<ItemWriter>();
            logger.info("Composite Writer Started");
            writers.add(summaryWriter());
            writers.add(detailsWriter());
            writers.add(chartWriter());
            compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(writers);
            return compositeItemWriter;
        }
```

Our Questions

1. Do we need to make Composite writer and `JDBCwriter` "StepScope" to avoid any concurrency issues. As per the documentation says `JdbcBatchItemWriter` is thread-safe.
2. Do we get any delay while insert(Batch commit) because of default Bean scope .

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If a writer is documented to be thread safe, then you can use it in a multi-threaded step. I would configure each worker step with its own instances of reader/writer to make sure there is no concurrency issues.
2. I see no relation between the two. The idea of partitioning is that workers are executed in parallel, so you will have parallel transactions. Now using a shared writer in multiple parallel transactions vs using multiple writers is something you need to experiment and benchmark.